# Vb.net errors with OleDb connection string

Tags: vb.net, database-connection

Im using a small simple function to read from a database, and display the data in a datagridview.

```
Function ReadFromDataBase(query As String, Table As String, pName As String)

    Try
        Conn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & pName & ";Persist Security Info=False;")

        Try
            Call Conn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Could not connect")
        End Try

        If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Dim SQL As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, Conn)
            Dim DataAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQL)
            Dim DataTable As New DataTable(Table)
            DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)
            Return DataTable
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.ToString
    End Try

End Function
```

This code was completely working until I brought it home, I have changed the Data Source (pName) before I called the function. I call the function here:

```
Private Sub IpLoad() Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim query, table, pName As String
    query = "SELECT * FROM CONFIG_MonitoredServers WHERE sName = 'C-1' OR sName = 'C-2' OR sName = 'C-3'"
    table = "CONFIG_MonitoredServers"
    pName = "F:\!Computing\!Versions\service.accdb"
    DataGridView2.DataSource = (Helpers.ReadFromDataBase(query, table, pName))
    query = "SELECT * FROM CONFIG_MonitoredServers WHERE sName  <>'C-1' AND sName <> 'C-2' AND sName <> 'C-3'"
    DataGridView1.DataSource = (Helpers.ReadFromDataBase(query, table, query))
    LockDownDataGridView()
End Sub
```

I have no idea what I have done wrong, so any help that could be provided would be extremely helpful.
I am getting no actual errors, just the message box saying cannot connect, when I remove the try catch and the message box, I simply get nothing at all, the form loads with blank data grid views.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Without knowing what is the error it is just a guessing game. Are you sure that you have the ACCDB in that path? Is something related to a missing OleDbProvider? Please add details to your question using the EDIT linkbutton

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast
I have updated the post to show what you have asked. I am sure the path is correct and being put in correctly, as I have simply shift clicked and used copy path from file explorer and then pasted it in. I have also replaced pName in the function with the path to make sure there was no error there.

Comment: Remove both the try catch in your ReadFromDataBase method. This will allow the exception to be seen interrupting your code on the Open line. Otherwise the external catch returns with the error message, but you don't show it On a side note. It is clear that you have Option Strict set to Off and this is really bad because allows both a string and a datatable to be returned from the ReadFromDatabase code.....

Comment: Only thing about turning option strict on is that I honestly think that my programming is currently too sloppy to turn on mid project. However I will attempt to clear up the code a little. The error Im now getting after removing the try catches is "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

Comment: Yes, that's the generic text, if you look at the INNEREXCEPTION message you will find more details

Comment: The inner exception is blank

Answer (score 0):

Probably sounds daft, but open Access. Sometimes there's a "first run" installation dialog that breaks OleDB until its completed.